# Is there a one liner to verify XML string structure?

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a string:

```
Dim strXMLTags As String = "<tags><test>1</test></tags>"
```

And I want to verify that all opening tags have a closing tag in the proper place.  So if I put the previous string through, it'd work.  However, if I put:

```
Dim strXMLTags As String = "<tags><test>1</test>"
```

Then I want it to give me an error.  Is there an XML structure checker or something of the sorts?  Or should I just try and load it to an XML document and if it errors then, then I know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would indeed be to try loading it into an xml document, and see if it crashes or not.

Comment: Dern.  I wish there were more boolean functions.  :)

Comment: You could always make one, an extension method on the string-class, for example.

Comment: I'm trying to create as little new code as possible.  I had/have one, but I'm using indexes, and cutting the strings, and I've only tested on examples given to me so I'm not sure if they'd work in every situation.  And I don't have much time to test, need to get the product done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wouldn't know of a one-liner, but there are ways to check for valid XML:

1. XSDs
2. HTML Tidy
3. Creating a temporary XML file and checking it's validity

1: XSDs - no need to explain here. When you have a correct schema for your XML you can validate against an XSD and see errors right away, this way you would even find missings tags etc.

2: HTMLTidy is the best resource for cleaning up messy HTML code. I am sure you could create something to only check your code. Check the [HTMLTidy SourceForge](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) page and a [Tidy .NET Implementation](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/20505) here.

3: Temp XML - (my personal favorite) just create a new `XmlTextReader` and after writing your XML somewhere temporary read it in again and check for errors. There is [some sample code on this page](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/XML/ValidateXMLdocumentwithValidationErrorHandler.htm), it uses a ValidationSchema though which you might not have? Actually there is are some posts about [XML Validation in VB.Net](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/XML/XML-Validation.htm) on that page.